# Navigation properties not being loaded after upgrading EF 4.1 to 6.1.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've recently upgraded Entity Framework version 4.1 to 6.1.2 targeting .Net framework 4.0. It has database first approach.

The problem I am facing is, before upgrading all navigation properties are loaded correctly but after upgradation it returns always Null.

Here is the current configuration after upgradation which exact same as before.

1. lazy loading is enabled.
2. Proxy is enabled.
3. I've deleted previously created entities and regenerated DBContext and all entity classes using EF 6.1 code generator (T4 templates)
4. All other things are working fine. Just navigation properties are not working.

As an example, this below is working fine before upgradation.

```
var listResult = entities.sampleEntity.where(c=>c.active).ToList();
var result = listResult.navigationProperty1.navigationCollection1.select(c=>c.active).firstOrDefault().Id;
```

Am I missing any configuration after upgrading EF? As of now I've following two solution to try out.

1. Rewrite all queries to load related entities. This has risk of changing many number of queries.
2. Once again upgrade EF 6.1.2 with DataContext code generator. This has risk as it is not going to supported from EF 7 i guess. And it is recommended to use DBContext.

EDIT:

I've used EF 6.x EntityObject Generator to use ObjectContext API with EF 6. Everything is working fine same as before upgrading the version.

Thanks,
Fenil

Comment: what do you mean by 'upgrade'? can't you just **create** higher version?

Comment: upgrade means, we've an existing data layer project using EF 4.1. We need to upgraded EF version from 4.1. to 6.1.2 in that existing project.

Comment: Check if the generated navigation properties are marked `virtual`.

Comment: @IvanStoev yes those properties are marked virtual. Auto generated using t4 templates. I've checked them.

Comment: @FenilRathod what's difference between 'upgrade' and 'create', do you really need 'upgrade'?

Comment: Let try this. If you expand `listResult` in the debugger, does it contain proxy class instances or just plain entity instances?

Comment: Off-topic, but that's a very expensive way to obtain only one ID value. On-topic: does the edmx look OK? I mean: does it show all expected relationships?

Comment: @GertArnold; Yes, I know it is very expensive :) legacy code written before 3-4 years. Now performance issues are coming and as a remedy, i am upgrading version first. Edmx looks ok to me and showing all relation. few navigation properties are loading perfect although. such deep level navigation are not being loaded.

Comment: That's interesting. You should try to find the key difference between the loading and the non-loading properties. Maybe collections do and references don't? Hard to tell anything useful from here.

Comment: Well, probably you can provide more code or details. Example code from post cannot work at all because `listResult` is not an entity and cannot contain `navigationProperty1`

Comment: @IvanStoev it contains Entity Classes and Entity Collections containing all other EF related stuff

Comment: As @Gert said, there is nothing we can do based on the provided information. If you can provide small reproducible example (a.k.a. [mcve]), we can take a look at it.

Comment: @DenisKrasakov Using objectcontext API, it is providing all related navigation properties and collection after doing .ToList()